# How to make the StatusBar transparent on Android4.2

Tags: java, android, statusbar, transparent

It is knowed that the `StatusBar` is black default of Andriod 4.2.
However,I want to make the `StatusBar` *transparent* on Launcher and change to be black when it come into an activity. And then,when it come back to the `Launcher`,the `StatusBar` recover to transparent.

---

There is a way to implement,but it do not work perfectly(the `Activity` open firstly and the `StatusBar` turn transparent slowly,No strict synchronization).

1. set `"status_bar_background"` to be `#00000000;`
2. delete the code `"mStatusBarWindow.setBackground(null);"` which in method   `"makeStatusBarView()"` of PhoneStatusBar.java;
3. Edit `mPixelFormat = PixelFormat.OPAQUE to mPixelFormat = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT`;
4. change the code in `WindowStateAnimator.java`
   `updateSurfaceWindowCrop()`, after the code line
   `"applyDecorRect(mService.mSystemDecorRect);"`

Added:

```
if(w.mAttrs.type == LayoutParams.TYPE_WALLPAPER) {
         w.mSystemDecorRect.top = 0; 
   }
```

Comment: you can't. It's only available for 5.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

I think cannot change StatusBar. If you want change, you has to change SystemUI
. You can references via link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2366476

Answer (score 0):

Hide the status bar and use you own header instead of it, best Solution.